# In Scala, create a nested HashMap of length N given a list of length N

Tags: java, scala

How can I create a nested hashmap given a list of values?

```
List(1,2,3,4).toMap => Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> 4)))
```

After that, how can I merge it with another map?

```
List(1,2,3,4).toMap => Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> 4)))
List(1,2,3,5).toMap => Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> 5)))
Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> List(4,5)))
```

I basically want to perform

```
List(List(1,2,3,8), List(2,3,7,9)).groupBy(x => x(0)).
groupBy(x => x(1)).
groupBy(x=>x(2)) 
... 
...
.groupBy(x=>x(n))
```

Where N is the length of the values within the inner lists.

Comment: Are the lists always of length 4? Otherwise the type of the Maps depend on the size of the list, which I don't think can be done.

Comment: Length is variable :(

Comment: Then we need more information about your use-cases for the resulting Maps, as it's an odd data structure.

Comment: I have a list of rows that I am grouping by hierarchical columns. e.g. continents -> countries -> cities. I need to be able to convert the list of rows into a treelike structure for traversal.

Comment: Are the lists all the same length in any particular scenario? What is the desired result of merging `List(1,2,3,4)` and `List(1,2,4,5)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve something close to your 1st request without too much difficulty.

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).foldRight(Map[Int,Map[Int,_]]()){case (a,b) => Map(a->b)}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, _]] 
     = Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> Map(4 -> Map()))))
```

But I don't think there's enough information to fully comprehend your 2nd request.  For example: How would the following lists be merged?

```
List(1,2,3,8)
List(2,3,7,9)
```

---

**UPDATE**

From your comments it sounds like maybe the best approach might be to merge the lists before the nesting.  This could be done a number of different ways, depending on your requirements.

For example: If order is important (and it looks like it is), can the list be easily sorted?  If your using `Int` then that's trivial.

```
def nest[A](input: List[A]): Map[A, Map[A,_]] =
  input.foldRight(Map[A,Map[A,_]]()){case (a,b) => Map(a->b)}

val lst1 = List(1,2,3,8)
val lst2 = List(2,3,7,9)
val result = nest( (lst1 ++ lst2).distinct.sorted )
//result: Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> Map(7 -> Map(8 -> Map(9 -> Map()))))))
```

But I suspect that these simple minded examples might be drifting away from your real-world use cases.

Comment: Look again.  The offered solution isn't restricted by list length.  You can `foldRight()` on a list of any length.

Comment: Okay this is fantastic!

Comment: But look at the resulting type of the Map :( The OP's data structure is really a tree, and probably should be implemented as such.

Comment: @DrJonesYu, please be explicit about the result of those example lists. It's not obvious and there are several possible answers.

Comment: I basically want to perform List(List(1,2,3,8), List(2,3,7,9)).groupBy(x => x(0)).groupBy(x => x(1)).groupBy(x=>x(2)) for the length of the values within the inner lists.

Answer (score 0):

We can improve the result a bit by recognizing that the initial value in the `foldRight` is the last two elements of the list. Namely, `3` and `4` becomes `Map(3 -> 4 )` which can be used as the initial value in the fold by doing some ugly indexing.

```
scala> val xs = List(1,2,3,4)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> xs.dropRight(2).foldRight(Map[Int, Any](xs(xs.length - 2) -> xs(xs.length - 1)))((a,b) => Map(a -> b))
res1: ... = Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> 4)))
```

Works with longer list too:

```
scala> xs.dropRight(2).foldRight(Map[Int, Any](xs(xs.length - 2) -> xs(xs.length - 1)))((a,b) => Map(a -> b))
res6: ... = Map(1 -> Map(2 -> Map(3 -> Map(4 -> Map(5 -> Map(6 -> Map(7 -> Map(8 -> 9))))))))
```